# How to detect if a specific file exists in Vimscript?

Tags: vim, file-exists

I'm looking for an elegant way in Vimscript to check if a file exists in the current directory.

I came up with the code below but I'm not sure if that's the most elegant solution (I'll set a Vim option if the file exists). Is there any way of not having to do another comparison of the filename?

Maybe use a different built-in function from Vim?

```
:function! SomeCheck()
:   if findfile("SpecificFile", ".") == "SpecificFile"
:       echo "SpecificFile exists"
:   endif
:endfunction
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

With a bit of searching in `vim man` I've found this, which looks much better that the original:

```
:function! SomeCheck()
:   if filereadable("SpecificFile")
:       echo "SpecificFile exists"
:   endif
:endfunction
```

Comment: What if SpecificFile exists, but is not readable for current user. Maybe findfile is better.

Comment: The help for `filereadable` mentions you can use `glob` if you don't care about readability.

Comment: if filereadable(expand("~/.vim/bundle/vundle/README.md"))
        let g:hasVundle = 1
    endif

Comment: @metaphy that's an excellent comment, I've added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205873/327074) based on that to give it more visibility, but if you want the credit feel free to add your own answer and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 69):

Some of the comments express concerns about `filereadable` and using `glob` instead. This addresses the issue of having a file that does exist, but permissions prevent it from being read. If you want to detect such cases, the following will work:

```
:if !empty(glob("path/to/file"))
:   echo "File exists."
:endif
```

Comment: I get `E116: Invalid arguments for function`. How do you specify the file relative to the home directory to check for a plugin? (See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30444477/3596168))

Comment: Are you talking about the user home directory? I would guess just a `~`, but I'm not positive. What arguments did you supply when you got that error?

Comment: I tried it with `~`, and it gave that error. Now I tried again and it works... :-)

Comment: Probably just a typo or something. But glad it worked for you!

Comment: Unlike the other answer, this appears to work for directories, too.

Comment: This also works to expand environment variables where filereadable does not

Comment: Note that if the file path is not a constant then it may cause problem with file names contains `*` or `?` on Linux. See `:h wildcard` for details.

Answer (score 24):

Giving some more visibility to [metaphy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098521/how-to-detect-if-a-specific-file-exists-in-vimscript#comment35527158_3098685) on the accepted answer:

> ```
> if filereadable(expand("~/.vim/bundle/vundle/README.md")) let g:hasVundle = 1 endif`
> ```

`filereadable` is what is required, if you are using `~` in your file path, there's an extra handy step of `expand`:

```lua
function! SomeCheck()
   if filereadable(expand("SpecificFile"))
       echo "SpecificFile exists"
   endif
endfunction
```

For example

- `:echo filereadable('~/.vimrc')` gives `0`,
- `:echo filereadable(expand('~/.vimrc'))` gives `1`

Answer (score 6):

Sorry if it's too late, but doing

```
if !empty(expand(glob("filename")))
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exists"
endif
```

works fine for me