# VimL: Checking if function exists

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

right now I'm cleaning up my `.vimrc` file to make sure it's compatible on most systems.

In my statusline I use a function that another plugin sets, the `GitBranchInfoString()` function introduced by [this plugin](https://github.com/taq/vim-git-branch-info).

What I wanna do is check if this function is set, and only then add it to the statusline. It would be in it's own line so I just need to check for it.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for all your help!

EDIT:

I have the following:

```
if exists('*GitBranchInfoString')
    let &stl.='%{GitBranchInfoString()}'
endif
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use

```
if exists("*GitBranchInfoString")
    " do stuff here
endif
```

Comment: It does check for it, but for some reason it doesn't apply it to the statusline. I updated question with what I have.

Comment: @Eduan vimrc is sourced before any plugins are loaded. Use this condition on `VimEnter` event, put statusline stuff into `~/.vim/after/plugin/statusline.vim` (`statusline` can be any name) or do `runtime plugin/git-branch-info.vim` prior to the check (it will forbid you to disable this plugin with `--noplugin` option though; other solutions won’t).

Comment: I see, I will try that later, and give you any feedback. :)

Comment: For a more complete answer: http://superuser.com/questions/552323/how-can-i-test-for-plugins-and-only-include-them-if-they-exist-in-vimrc

Answer (score 9):

Just as an alternative you may also use a regexp to decide if the plugin at hand is in your `runtimepath`:

```
if &rtp =~ 'plugin-name'
    ...
endif
```

This has the advantage that it works with plugins that only have vimscript code in the `autoload` directory, which in turn can't be detected when .vimrc is initially parsed since the autoload snippets are loaded at the time of a function call.

Answer (score 7):

The currently selected answer doesn't work for me (using Vim 7.4 / Ubuntu).
I believe that's because:

> .vimrc is sourced before any plugins are loaded

As @ZyX noted this in a comment.

My preferred method is just to **check for the existence of the plugin file**. 
I find this cleaner than writing a separate function in an external file.

```
if !empty(glob("path/to/plugin.vim"))
   echo "File exists."
endif
```

Comment: +1. Sample for checking if Syntastic is installed via Vundle: `if !empty(glob(expand("<sfile>:p:h") . "/.vim/bundle/syntastic"))`. (See [here](http://superuser.com/a/120011/4160).)